# isInfixOf and finding a string within a string

Tags: string, haskell

The problem I have is that I am using `isInfixOf` on a string below to check whether the word I am looking for is within the string, the below works up to a certain point.

```
> "world" `isInfixOf` "hello world"
True
```

but what if it's part of another word it still returns TRUE as below:

```
> "wor" `isInfixOf` "hello world"
True
```

I am trying to find out whether the word passed in is in the string I am looking for but it is not part of another song.

I have tried a lot of methods but I am not sure how I could make sure the word is not part of a another word.

WORDS does not work because it doesn't strip the string of it's punc character.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some regular expression packages could be helpful here.

For example, using [regex-prce-builtin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-builtin).

```
> :m + Text.Regex.PCRE
> "Hello world" =~ "\\bworld\\b" :: Bool
True
it :: Bool
> "Hello world" =~ "\\bwor\\b" :: Bool
False
```

`\\b` stands for `\b` word boundary, which is used in Perl regular expressions.

So we can define new `isInfixOf` analogue using `(=~)`.

```
> let s `isInfixOf_` l = l =~ ("\\b" ++ s ++ "\\b") :: Bool
isInfixOf_ :: RegexLike Regex source1 => [Char] -> source1 -> Bool
> "wor" `isInfixOf_` "Hello world"
False
it :: Bool
> "world" `isInfixOf_` "Hello world"
True
it :: Bool
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a different approach. The [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:words) function creates a list of strings that contains all of the words in a string. The [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:elem) function tells if something is part of a list. So, you could use `elem "world" (words "hello world")`. There are other solutions involving regular expressions, but this one is probably the simplest.

Comment: It should be noted that `words "hello, world" == ["hello,", "world"]` (punctuation isn't stripped).

Comment: @dbaupp The `splitOneOf` function from [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitOneOf) may help solve that problem.